# What are the "tmp" .RAW files showing up when importing pics from Android to Windows PC?

Tags: windows-10, android, photos, import

When importing photos taken from my Samsung Galaxy S6 into Windows 10, sometimes I get anomalous photos imported that are not in my camera's galaxy.

The anomalous imported images vary in their contents: sometimes they are 1px*1px white image files of a few kb size; sometimes they are graphics like an arrow direction sign, a generic scene of a camera displayed over a cityscape like an ad, or an octagon; sometimes they are files that seem like images but don't open correctly; sometimes they are screenshots of my phone homescreen but they are not screenshots that appear in my phone gallery as when I intentionally take a screenshot. In my last test case, my import included 6 files named "tmp0", "tmp1" ... "tmp5" all .RAW format and somewhat large (one is 8MB, one is 15MB). These files sometimes have almost no metadata, and in some cases they have timestamps that happened when the phone was off and I was asleep! So far I've noticed they all have File Attributes="A" under Properties > Details > File, but I'm not sure what that means.

Here are some specs on the import:

- Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android v7.0
- Windows 10 HP laptop
- To import, I connect phone to PC via USB then Windows Photos pops up. It
  searches for new images, I then select which of the new ones I want to import and have options on what system to name & save them through and if deleting after importing, then I start the process. It's at that point - where Windows Photos is suggesting what images to import - that I see these weird images which aren't showing up on my phone's gallery.

I use the same import system to import photos from a different camera which connects to the PC via an SD card. When going off the SD card, I never get these weird images, so this seems specific to the Android/Windows connection.

Here's a screenshot of the weird photos I get when importing images from my phone, which are not in my phone's gallery:

[image: screenshot of weird images]

Comment: "A" attribute is known as the archive bit- meaning that a backup program hasn't marked the file as backed up.

Do you see the photos at all on the phone through the USB connection in Windows?

Comment: If you check in your File browser, are these odd images located in a specific folder?

Comment: Yes @xavier_fakerat these odd images are visible in the phone (LPE folder as you noted in answer) when viewed via PC.

Comment: @AllenHoward yes. As I commented on xavier's answer, the new question is how to stop the backup program from wanting to backup those odd images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems these temporary images are originating from the LPE folder.

Basing on the explanation give on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47463693/7551330):

> The LPE folder is used by Samsung's Camera and Photo Editor apps. The
>   files inside are photos in a `raw` format. If you open the file in
>   photoshop, you can make out the image somewhat. The specifics of the
>   image bit orders are not known.

One Samsung [user](https://warosu.org/g/thread/59410233) acknowledges that this folder,  continuously and periodically creates/modifies `tmp*.raw` files every day at arbitrary times.

About the nature of their appearance of these temporary images, they seem to come in fragments and unusual colours:

> It (the `.raw` file) contains your last image in a very specific way: the first quad
>   of image in a blue light, the second in red etc.

and [some suggest](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS7/comments/6cto4q/lpe_folder/) it comes from specific apps whose screenshot would have been taken randomly:

> If I remember correctly, mine is usually filled with RAW files which,
>   when opened in Photoshop, are just screenshots of my apps at different
>   points.

**What are they used for?**

One user suggest that;

These temporary raw files (`tmp0.raw` etc) which are made by the Samsung camera are created **to aid fast editing of the pictures you take**. New `raw` files are also created when you use the built-in photo editor to add effects to your photos.

One consenquence about these files is the potential drive space they can take up as they can be large.

> These are temporary files and can be **safely deleted**.

**Acknowledgements**

- [My S7 has a virus](https://www.androidauthority.com/community/threads/help-my-s7-has-a-virus.38416/)
- [function of LPE folder android on android 6+ and tmp .raw files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42364787/7551330)

Comment: Maybe a sepeate question...how can they stop being imported? Need to set a rule for the importer or something

Comment: To avoid this, trying importing your photos manually. [See Complete Guide to Importing Your Photos in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos/complete-guide-to-importing-your-photos-in-windows/d8258fff-729e-45df-8afd-1f1195d7b6c5?auth=1)

Answer (score 1):

that occurs on every phone, I guess. thumbnails, caches and temp files are created automatically by systems for quicker navigations. you can delete them. won't harm you anyway.